# Mirror an object feet away from parent object instead right next to it?

Tags: modeling, camera, mirror

How can i get this chunk of geometry to mirror to the other side of the room instead of right next to the object mirroring it?. Also are there any camera settings that would benefit me doing the exterior then working on the interior instead of vice versa?. I ended up pulling up the back wall starting the wood work on that wall then i'm going to pull up a side wall when that's done and start it's wood work i.e trim and inlays etc.because the camera becomes unresponsive otherwise there has to be way to build a structure then work on the guts of it.[image]

Answer (score 0):

In object mode choose your wall and go into edit mode. Select the front face of your wall and then <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>s</kbd>. Choose Cursor to selected. It will place the 3D cursor at the centre of the face (the front of your wall).

[image]

Go back into Object mode and select your door (the pink cube in my case). Right click and select Set Origin > Origin to 3D cursor.

[image]

The pivot point of the cube will move to the centre of your wall (front face).

Add a mirror modifier to the cube and set the axis (in my case the Y)

[image]

The mirrored cube will mirror across the pivot point.

For your walls if they are planes (single faces) then make sure your normals are facing the interior of the room and turn off backface culling. This means you can work inside your room without the faces (walls getting in the way).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks man. My  walls though are 8 in thick not planar , I ended up doing this because of additions that connect to the outside walls and they kept poking through, i would delete edges and/or  faces but kept running into one problem or another lol.

Comment: You can select the outer walls and hide them   \ h and alt h to unhide.

Comment: I did that but the camera knows they're still there lol. and gets slow to almost unmovable when it nears even invisible geometry?.